# Postgresql flask-sqlalchemy permission denied to set parameter > "log_statement_stats"

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm attempting to initialise my database for a flask app using flask-sqlalchemy.

I've received the following fatal error.

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError)
> connection to server at "occ-appdc1001" (172.25.208.1), port 5432
> failed: FATAL:  permission denied to set parameter
> "log_statement_stats"

My connection string is:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "postgresql://prodcent_user:XXXXX@SERVER:5432/appdata?options=-search_path=datamanager"
```

I've tried adding permissions as follows:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA datamanager TO prodcent_user ;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA datamanager TO prodcent_user ;

GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA datamanager TO prodcent_user ;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA datamanager TO prodcent_user ;
GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA datamanager TO prodcent_user ;

GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA datamanager TO prodcent_user ;
GRANT ALL ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA datamanager TO prodcent_user ;
GRANT ALL ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA datamanager TO prodcent_user ;
```

But still have the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Only the superuser can [change `log_statement_stats`](https://postgresqlco.nf/doc/en/param/log_statement_stats/). It appears you are using `prodcent_user`, which probably doesn't have superuser privileges.

You can try either using a superuser or find a way to grant superuser privileges to `prodcent_user`